# An if statement to run based on various amounts of criteria being greater than 0

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing an if statement with 5 separate criteria based on whether they are greater than zero.

I want 6 separate if statements based on whether 0 criteria >0, 1 criteria > 0 , 2 etc... up to 5 criteria > 0.  I was trying to do this with OR and AND statements, but it's obviously not the solution.

What I'm essentially after:

```
If 0 Criteria > 0 Then
    Do this
ElseIf 1 Criteria > 0 Then
    Do this
ElseIf 2 Criteria > 0 Then
    Do this
....
ElseIf 5 Criteria > 0 Then
    Do this
End If
```

Comment: So you have 5 independent numeric variables and want a different action depending on how many are 0?

Comment: The criteria, are they cells on a worksheet?  Are those cells contiguous?

Answer (score 1):

You could use evaluate on an array of the criteria with SUMPRODUCT

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Dim criteria1 As Long, criteria2 As Long,criteria3 As Long
    Dim criteria4 As Long, criteria5 As Long, arr()
    Dim numGreaterThanZero As Long

    criteria1 = -1
    criteria2 = 3
    criteria3 = 0
    criteria4 = 5
    criteria5 = 6

    arr = Array(criteria1, criteria2, criteria3, criteria4, criteria5)

    numGreaterThanZero = Application.Evaluate("=SUMPRODUCT(--({" & Join$(arr, ";") & "}>0))")

    Select Case numGreaterThanZero

    Case 1
    Case 2
    Case 3
    Case 4
    Case 5

    End Select
End Sub
```

---

If you actually just want to test the conditions separately (and not a cumulative count) and exit at first True then:

```
Select Case True

Criteria1 > 0
'Do Something

Criteria2> 0
'Do something else

End Select
```

Comment: Sorry I missed the then statements, silly mistake! Yes I literally thought after posting doing it top down might be the best way, so it will then bypass the next elseif statement. Thank you

Comment: Depends if you need to run all the tests or only need the up to the first that evaluates to True. Which is it?

Comment: Only up to the first one that is true

Comment: Was my original answer what you wanted then? Select Case statement ? I will add back in .

Answer (score 1):

(this is untested)

```
Dim c as long

c = 0

If criteria1 = 0 then CritNo = CritNo + 1
If criteria2 = 0 then CritNo = CritNo + 1
If criteria3 = 0 then CritNo = CritNo + 1
If criteria4 = 0 then CritNo = CritNo + 1
If criteria5 = 0 then CritNo = CritNo + 1
If criteria6 = 0 then CritNo = CritNo + 1

Select case CritNo 
    Case 1
         Do stuff
    Case 2
         Do other stuff
    ...
    Case Else
         Do nothing
End select
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another idea:

```
Select Case Abs(criteria1 > 0) + Abs(criteria2 > 0) + Abs(criteria3 > 0) + Abs(criteria4 > 0) + Abs(criteria5 > 0)
   Case 0
      MsgBox "0 criteria"
   Case 1
      MsgBox "1 criteria"
   Case 2
      MsgBox "2 criteria"
   Case 3
      MsgBox "3 criteria"
   Case 4
      MsgBox "4 criteria"
   Case 5
      MsgBox "5 criteria"
End Select
```

Comment: You could also `-(criteria1 > 0)  + -(...`